# For loop Bash Scripting with If Else character

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "abc" "efg" "lmn" 
do
    for j in 9 7 3 "lmn" 
    do
        if (( $j==$i ))
        then
            echo $i
        fi
    done

done
```

Expected Output:
lmn

Output:
abc
efg
lmn

Comment: `(( ))` evaluates the contents are an arithmetic expression, which cannot do string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use square brackets `[]` and not `()`

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "abc" "efg" "lmn" 
do
    for j in 9 7 3 "lmn" 
    do
        if [[ $j == $i  ]]
        then
            echo $i
        fi
    done

done
```

the above works

Output:

`lmn`

The reason for using `[]` is clearly explained [in this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72260/what-is-the-difference-between-if-and-in-bash)